# Prove any semistandard Ehrhart form has at least one totally ramified subform

Tags: abstract-algebra, ramification

I'm self-studying finite ramification theory, and I found the following problem:

> Let $\Phi$ be a semistandard Ehrhart form (i.e. its entries are weakly increasing). Prove that $\Phi$ has at least one totally ramified subform.

I thought this would be easy at first but quickly ran into trouble. Here's what I tried:

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $S$ be the set of all points in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ that are fixed by the action of $\Phi$. Since $\Phi$ is semistandard, $|S|\geq 1$. Then by the Fixed Point-Subform correspondence theorem, the number of ramified subforms of $\Phi$ equals $|S|$.

**However**, how can I show that at least one of these subforms is *totally* ramified (i.e. its image contains no powers of $p$)? The correspondence theorem doesn't immediately yield this. We probably need to again use the fact that $\Phi$ was assumed semistandard. Can anyone provide a hint here on how to proceed?

Comment: Should I ask this on mathoverflow?

Comment: Hi Doug. There may be someone here who knows about this. It is not me, however. You may need to give it some time. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: dear Doug, welcome to math stackexchange! apologies for my ignorance, but what is an "Ehrhart form"? I did a quick google search but couldn't seem to find anything